# Align image and text using <span>

Tags: html, css, layout

[JSFIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/mCtdH/)

```
<span class="date">January 27, 2014</span>
<span class="comment">3</span>



.comment {
    background: url(http://shrani.si/f/3E/11P/1bbcqgfF/comments.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 12px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #9e988e;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.date {
    background: url(http://shrani.si/f/46/3O/31QIdb94/calendar.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: 12px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #9e988e;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

What do I need to add so this will work so full image gets displayed and text displays on right, aligned by middle of image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, specify a big enough padding to create space for the icon. It is just a background image, it reserves no space for itself, you have to take care of it:

```
padding-left: 15px;
```

For the vertical alignment, specify `center` for the vertical [background-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position):

```
background: url(xy/calendar.png) no-repeat left center;
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mCtdH/1/)

Comment: With this CSS text isn't aligned in line with image on left, I want text to be aligned by the centre of image.

Comment: @user3187469 Hm, for me it is quite fine. You checked my demo and don't see it aligned? Which browser?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the images to act as elements, you should make them elements.  Background images are supposed to be behind text or other elements.  So if you want you images to show through, it is best to add them as image elements rather than background images.  Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNf5k/3/).

**HTML:**

```
<span class="date"><img src='http://shrani.si/f/46/3O/31QIdb94/calendar.png'/>January 27, 2014</span>
<span class="comment"><img src='http://shrani.si/f/46/3O/31QIdb94/calendar.png'/>3</span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.comment {
display: inline-block;
color: #9e988e;
font-size: 12px;
}

.date {
display: inline-block;
color: #9e988e;
font-size: 12px;
}
.date img, .comment img{
    height:12px;
    width:12px;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```